# javascript function for calculating

Tags: javascript

I meet a trouble with a function. actually I need to make this function to perform a calculation on some text fields. When I worked on a single line no problems. But recently, someone asked to make a table with multiple lines (one line can be added dynamically) so, I do the following function so that it can not only duplicate line but id change all the fields concerned, so I add class to these fields. therefore I proceed as follows:

```
function clone(line) {

     newLine = line.cloneNode(true);
     line.parentNode.appendChild(newLine);
     var tab = document.getElementsByClassName('libelle_debours')
     var i = -1;
     while (tab[++i]) {
         tab[i].setAttribute("id", "_" + i);
     };
     var cab = document.getElementsByClassName('ht_no_tva')
     var j = -1;
     while (cab[++j]) {
         cab[j].setAttribute("id", "_" + j);
     };
     var dab = document.getElementsByClassName('ht_tva')
     var k = -1;
     while (dab[++k]) {
         dab[k].setAttribute("id", "_" + k);
     };
     var eab = document.getElementsByClassName('taux')
     var l = -1;
     while (eab[++l]) {
         eab[l].setAttribute("id", "_" + l);
     };
     var fab = document.getElementsByClassName('tva')
     var m = -1;
     while (fab[++m]) {
         fab[m].setAttribute("id", "_" + m);
     };

 }

 function delRow() {
     var current = window.event.srcElement;
     //here we will delete the line
     while ((current = current.parentElement) && current.tagName != "TR");
     current.parentElement.removeChild(current);
 }
```

The problem in fact is the second function that is used to make the calculation:

```
 function calcdebours() {
            var taux = document.getElementById('debours_taux_tva').value;
            var ht_no_tva = document.getElementById('debours_montant_ht_no_tva').value;
            var ht_tva = document.getElementById('debours_montant_ht_tva').value;
            var tva = Math.round((((ht_tva) * (taux)) / 100) * 100) / 100;;
            if (taux == '') {
                taux = 0;
            }
            if (ht_no_tva == '') {
                ht_no_tva = 0;
            }
            if (ht_tva == '') {
                ht_tva = 0;
            }
            document.getElementById('debours_montant_tva').value = tva;
            document.getElementById('debours_montant_ttc').value = (tva) + parseFloat(ht_tva) + parseFloat(ht_no_tva)


        }

        function 

montant_debours() {
        var ttc = document.getElementById('debours_montant_ttc').value;
        var ttc2 = document.getElementById('debours_montant_ttc2').value;
        if (ttc == '') {
            var ttc = 0;
        } else {
            var ttc = document.getElementById('debours_montant_ttc').value;
        }
        if (ttc2 == '') {
            var ttc2 = 0;
        } else {
            var ttc2 = document.getElementById('debours_montant_ttc2').value;
        }
        tx = parseFloat(ttc) + parseFloat(ttc2);
        document.getElementById('ttc_cheque').value = Math.round(tx * 100) / 100;
    }
```

As Id are not the same, do I have to create as many functions
there are lines?

Is it possible to fit a single function to process each line?

If so can you tell me how?

Comment: Why you are not using jquery?

Comment: because I really tried to used it but it is too much complicated for a brain like me

Comment: Ok so without jQuery you I don't see easy way out, later I'll post answer with jQuery with explanations.

Comment: Yeah Stanislas, Jquery is much simpler than trying to get everything by id. It's scary, but if you stick with it you'll find that it takes much less brain power.

Comment: I've bought a book in amazon but it is not yet coming, so I can not learn, on internet eerything I found was not easy to be understand. I really start from nothing. So Actualy I dynamicly changed the Id I also change the attribute so each function start with a numver like that onchange="calc(1)" the number 1 is incremented for each line. Is there a way I can use the number one as a var on my function ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you can use for loop and append increment to the end of element's id. Like this:

```
trs = document.getElementById('container Id').getElementsByTagName('tr');
For (var i = 1, i <= trs.length; i++)
{
    var el = document.getElementById('debours_montant_ttc' + i);
}
```